# android get screen size including the size of status bar and software navigation bar

Tags: android, android-screen

How can I get the size of the screen in pixels with navigation bar and status bar being included?

I have already tried getting the size using `DisplayMetrics` but the size doesn't include the software navigation bar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

software navigation is added since API 17 (JELLY_BEAN_MR1) so we need the to include the size of navigation bar only in API 17 and above.
and note that when you get the screen size it is **based on the current orientation.**

```
public void setScreenSize(Context context) {
    int x, y, orientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    WindowManager wm = ((WindowManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        Point screenSize = new Point();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            display.getRealSize(screenSize);
            x = screenSize.x;
            y = screenSize.y;
        } else {
            display.getSize(screenSize);
            x = screenSize.x;
            y = screenSize.y;
        }
    } else {
        x = display.getWidth();
        y = display.getHeight();
    }

    int width = getWidth(x, y, orientation);
    int height = getHeight(x, y, orientation);
}

private int getWidth(int x, int y, int orientation) {
    return orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? x : y;
}

private int getHeight(int x, int y, int orientation) {
    return orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? y : x;
}
```

[link to gist -> here](https://gist.github.com/hister/4a2e25fba3cdf657ff08)