# Service Screen Size

Tags: android, service

I know about using `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);` to grab screen size for an `activity`, but how can I go about getting the screen size for a `service`? Please let me know if I need to explain more.

Comment: Do you want to get screen size from service?

Comment: I want to get screen size of my device. I want to perform this in a Service class.

Comment: Found my answer. I realized how badly I worded that afterwards so sorry for wasting your time hehe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Get Screen dimensions from Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210769/android-get-screen-dimensions-from-service)

Comment: It is a duplicate. This post can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside your **service**:

```
WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
Display display = window.getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

OR

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel really silly for not trying to use getSystemService. I looked it up but couldn't find any use xD I have no coding background. I just research. Would you recommend anything I can read upon?

Comment: What I didnt take into count was the notification bar. I only get the screen size of everything below the notification bar. Can you help me further?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674378/android-get-screen-size-including-the-size-of-status-bar-and-software-navigation

Comment: the solution from link should work. This is what get from service with code from  my answer `setScreenSize: 1080--------1794` and this from Service with code from above link `setScreenSize: 1080--------1920` in my sample app

Comment: If the above solution worked for you, kindly accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What does that mean **Screen size for Service** ?

Service is a background process of app, it does not have a UI. (thus no screensize) You can read more about Services at **[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)**

Or if I am getting right , you want to access screen size from a service.

**An hack** will be to store screen size in preference when app starts from first activity. And then use it anywhere even when app is in background. Because screen size will not be changed.

**Edit**

After seeing your image, if it is a dialog, you can use below way to make your dialog full screen.

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)
```

Comment: Here is an image of my app. I am using a service class to allow my floating ui to overlay. http://oi67.tinypic.com/2hhk3sk.jpg

Comment: Sorry that wasn't what I was looking for hehe but I may have just worded it incorrectly. I did find my answer, but thank you anyways!

Comment: What was the issue then, and how did you resolve that?

Comment: From inside a service class, I wanted to get the size of the screen.

Comment: You could use `An hack` line solution

Comment: WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
Display display = window.getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

This worked very well for me, so I will just follow through with this. Thanks again.